# Retrieve data from oracle database using Ajax Jquery with spring Mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new with  ajax and Jquery , and I want to retrieve data from database and display it in a table in my view page . When I cliCk on a button, a record is added to database , I want to display it on the front end automatically.

I'm not using Hibernate , just a simple Jdbc connection.

Comment: I'd suggest reading some basic tutorial on jquery ajax requests and trying to solve problem by yourself. After that, if you stuck, post what you have tried. Just asking for solution without even trying to get into the topic is forbidden by the rules of stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm going to post what I've done..
Thanks anyway .